# How to calculate the mean of each variable in multiple columns based on specific types in one column in R?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, mean

I am new to R, so I would be grateful if someone can help me with this question.

I am using the data frames from the Corpora package in R as follows:

```
install.packages("corpora")
library("corpora")

data("BNCbiber")
data("BNCmeta")
```

and I have combined a column(text_type) from the BNCmeta to the BNCbiber data frame:

```
BNCombine <- cbind(BNCmeta$text_type, BNCbiber)
```

what I need to do now is to calculate the mean of each variable for each text type, and since they are many columns(65 columns) I am not sure how I should do it.

Comment: aggregate(BNCombine, by=list(BNCombine$textype), mean)

Comment: Hi SathishI have tried aggregare but it sent me the following error :Error in aggregate.data.frame(BNCombine, by = list(BNCombine$textype),  : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: I did not try it as I am away from the desk. Please read ?aggregate function documentation

Comment: ok, i will do as you said, thanks a lot

Comment: I also did this, but I am not sure if it is right:                       newBNCombibe <- BNCombine [order(BNCmeta$text_type),] 

newBNCombibe$means <- apply(newBNCombibe[,3:65],c(1,2), FUN=mean)

Comment: to be able to use `aggregate` you have to change the name you are using: ie `BNCombine <- cbind(text=BNCmeta$text_type, BNCbiber)` then use `aggregate(.~text,BNCombine[-2],mean)`. Why Am I removing the second column? Its not numeric. It is a bunch of id's and I guess you don't need it

Comment: thank you very much Onyambu. it worked perfectly

Comment: you are  welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(BNCombine[3:ncol(BNCombine)], by = list(BNCombine$`BNCmeta$text_type`), FUN = mean)
```

Comment: Hi Esteban, I tried your solution, it gives me the mean for each column, but how can I say that this mean for each column is based on the text types; which are 5 types, in the text_type column?

Comment: Thank you very much Esteban

Comment: Hi @ZaraKolagar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.